# Negate a range of characters inside a character class in regex

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I'm trying to match anything that doesn't belong to this regex
 `[_a-zA-Z]`.
Tried`^[_a-zA-Z]`
 but this matches regex at only starting of a line.
What should be the regex to solve this condition?
I'm using this in rules section of a flex file, giving `[^_a-zA-Z]` throws a warning rule cannot be matched.
Any way to remove this warning??

Comment: The tags `unix` and `identifier` don't make much sense here. I also believe this must be trivial to find using a search engine.

Comment: Thanks for editing. But now there is a `flex` tag. To me this seems like a pure regex question.

Comment: im trying to use this in a flex file. so included it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put that `^` inside the character class to negate it.

```
[^_a-zA-Z]
```

Now the above class is a negated class.

Comment: I was soo stressed i forgot the "^" would also negate a-z also.. sorry for posting this question.. should I delete the question now?

Comment: @ManojBharadwaj no, mark the answer so it will be helpful to others too

Comment: but adding this gives a warning "warning, rule cannot be matched" in lex rules section. why?

Answer (score 1):

I think the negation should be placed inside the brackets. Like this:

```
[^_a-zA-Z]
```

You should try this.